# How to add layers to a faceted chart in Altair?

Tags: python, altair

Altair is a lovely visualization lib, with nice intuitive visual grammar API. I am however struggling adding a layer with rule marks to a faceted chart.

Imagine you have a simple dataset:

```
print(df[['Year', 'Profile', 'Saison', 'Pos']].to_csv())
,Year,Profile,Saison,Pos
0,2017,6.0,Sommer,VL
1,2017,6.0,Winter,VL
13,2017,6.0,Winter,HL
12,2017,6.0,Sommer,HL
18,2017,6.0,Sommer,HR
6,2017,6.0,Sommer,VR
7,2017,6.0,Winter,VR
19,2017,6.0,Winter,HR
14,2018,5.5,Winter,HL
8,2018,5.5,Winter,VR
15,2018,5.5,Sommer,HL
20,2018,4.3,Winter,HR
21,2018,5.0,Sommer,HR
3,2018,5.5,Sommer,VL
2,2018,6.2,Winter,VL
9,2018,4.5,Sommer,VR
17,2019,4.5,Sommer,HL
11,2019,4.2,Sommer,VR
22,2019,3.5,Winter,HR
10,2019,5.28,Winter,VR
5,2019,4.6,Sommer,VL
4,2019,4.9,Winter,VL
16,2019,4.0,Winter,HL
23,2019,4.5,Sommer,HR
```

Than you can simply display it with:

```
base = alt.Chart(df[df.Saison=='Winter']).mark_bar().encode(x='Year:O', y='Profile:Q', column='Pos:N')
base
```

[image]

Than, let’s say I want to add horizontal marks to visualize some limits:

[image]

For that I define the DataSet:

```
print(Limits.to_csv())
,Profil
0,3.0
1,1.5
```

And add it to the collection of charts:

```
limits = alt.Chart(Limits).mark_rule(color='red').encode(y='Profil')
base + limits
```

This does not work and generates and error:

```
ValueError: Faceted charts cannot be layered.
```

How can I overcome this limitation? Underlying vega-light grammar apparently [supports](https://altair-viz.github.io/case_studies/exploring-weather.html) such complex composition of layers, but I cannot figure out the way how to express it in Altair.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot layer a facteted chart, because in general there is no guarantee that the contents of each layer contains compatible faceting.

However, you *can* facet a layered chart. It might look something like this:

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
import io

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""
,Year,Profile,Saison,Pos
0,2017,6.0,Sommer,VL
1,2017,6.0,Winter,VL
13,2017,6.0,Winter,HL
12,2017,6.0,Sommer,HL
18,2017,6.0,Sommer,HR
6,2017,6.0,Sommer,VR
7,2017,6.0,Winter,VR
19,2017,6.0,Winter,HR
14,2018,5.5,Winter,HL
8,2018,5.5,Winter,VR
15,2018,5.5,Sommer,HL
20,2018,4.3,Winter,HR
21,2018,5.0,Sommer,HR
3,2018,5.5,Sommer,VL
2,2018,6.2,Winter,VL
9,2018,4.5,Sommer,VR
17,2019,4.5,Sommer,HL
11,2019,4.2,Sommer,VR
22,2019,3.5,Winter,HR
10,2019,5.28,Winter,VR
5,2019,4.6,Sommer,VL
4,2019,4.9,Winter,VL
16,2019,4.0,Winter,HL
23,2019,4.5,Sommer,HR
"""))

bars = alt.Chart().mark_bar().encode(
    x='Year:O',
    y='Profile:Q',
)

limits = alt.Chart(
  pd.DataFrame({'Profil': [3, 1.5]})
).mark_rule(
  color='red'
).encode(y='Profil')

alt.layer(
    bars,
    limits,
    data=df[df.Saison=='Winter']
).facet(
    'Pos:N',
)
```

[image]

Specifying the data here is a little tricky: the `facet()` method keys-off the top-level data in the chart it's called on, so when you're faceting layers built from different datasets, you need to specify the relevant data at the top level.